# TypeScript - Completely disable property does not exist on object check / rule

Tags: typescript

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to disable that check in typescript completely with a rule, I know you can create types as any / other methods, but I'm specifically looking for a rule that will do this in the ts config file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an existing [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for that, no.  There's a [suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29950) to allow disabling errors by error number (the error you're referring to is [2339](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.6.3/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json#L1199-L1202), I think), but that hasn't been implemented.  Oh well.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: adding to jcalz issue reference, here is a similar one in `typescript-eslint` https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2273